# How to run JarSplice from the command line?

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick, jarsplice

I've tried `java -jar jarsplice.jar --help` and `"" /?` which just launches the UI. I'd like my game to automatically be packaged into a single jar when it's built so it would be very useful to be able to call it from the command line.

e.g-

```
java -jar jarsplice.jar -jars "..." -natives "..." -output "..." -exe -sh -mac
```

Comment: Related question on stack overflow: [command line parameters with JarSplice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998264/command-line-parameters-with-jarsplice)

Comment: What does your build process look like?  If you're using gradle, consider using [this](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) instead; jarsplice hasn't been updated in years afaik.  And if you're not using gradle for your java project, you should consider doing so.

Comment: Asking if software X does Y [is not the best fit for the site](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2383/should-we-consider-does-product-x-have-feature-y-type-questions-as-on-topic). I've reworded it so that you can get an answer, if there is such a thing.

Comment: @doppelgreener They are not related, at all, the other question is asking if you can pass parameters through to the wrapped game.

Comment: Or just use the maven:assembly plugin?

Comment: @dot_Sp0T This does not have the sam effect as the jar splicer.

Comment: @BasicallyAlanTuring as far as I understood it both create fat-jars. You might need to do some different steps with the assembly plugin and create your own .bat/.sh file to launch the jar with arguments - but at least you can integrate it in your build process instead of having to do steps manually each time?

Comment: Jar splice is a piece of software that unwraps natives from the jar and references them at runtime, you can't just package them in

Comment: @ShaunWild actually, *yes you can* package the natives in a jar. At least with LWJGL3 - and your question is tagged accordingly, so I assume you actually use it, yes? [Here](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?PHPSESSID=sdharfcarkv8qab1c2annepbg0&topic=36752.msg349689#msg349689)'s a link to a forum post over at JGO where kappa explains it back at the end of 2015. Afaik it's part of the stable build in the meanwhile, because I can build and deploy a single fat-jar with maven:assembly without any issues :/

Comment: @dot_Sp0T Oh okay, I'll bookmark that.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer: It's not possible

There are forks however that allow you to do this.

For example: https://github.com/lquesada/JarSplicePlus

Comment: Don't forget to mark your answer as Accepted if you're satisfied with it.